# XML frameworks in PHP

Tags: php, xml, performance, frameworks

In addition to this question: [iPhone network performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1049050/iphone-network-performance), I would like to know if there are any (very) good XML parsing frameworks out there for PHP.

PHP has great XML support already, but I wonder if it could be better (in terms of performance, memory usage, etc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[XMLReader](http://nl2.php.net/manual/en/book.xmlreader.php) and [XMLWriter](http://nl2.php.net/manual/en/book.xmlwriter.php) are probably your best options when it comes to performance.

These 2 have the benefit of not needing the full DOM tree of your xml in memory, although they aren't as convenient to work with.

Answer (score 1):

There are several:

- [SimpleXML](https://www.php.net/simplexml);
- [DOMDocument](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php);
- [xml_parse](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.xml-parse.php); and
- others.

SimpleXML is pretty easy to use but has some serious limitations, like an apparent inability to deal with elements that contain both text and other elements, for which I've had to use DOMDocument instead.

Comment: I am aware that there are more (I currently use SimpleXML) but I wonder if they are all just as fast .. I have a very simple structure (RSS like), so I'm not in need of any advanced functions.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a list of [PHP's PEAR XML packages](http://pear.php.net/packages.php?catpid=22&catname=XML&php=all)

And here are [PHP's PECL XML Packages](http://pecl.php.net/packages.php?catpid=22&catname=XML)

Comment: Thanks, although I do not understand the difference (yet) I will take a look at it!